# What should I return when my oData V4 method returns SingleResult<T> and nothing is found?

Tags: asp.net, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a controller method in an oData V4 project that returns SingleResult.  It queries a table that, when it has data in it, returns what it should. However when the app is new and the table is empty it gives a nondescript error:

```
"'SingleResult`1' cannot be serialized using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter."
```

My method looks something like the following:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual SingleResult<LoggerEntry> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        using (var gateway = this.Gateway.GetChild())
        {
            var model = gateway.GetLoggerEntry(key);
            // TODO: Check for null and tell the client NotFound
            return SingleResult.Create((new List<LoggerEntry>(){ model }).AsQueryable());
        }
    }
```

Because I am using SingleResult I am not able to just `return NotFound();`. I have tried to use an empty list but that gives me the same error. I can not find an example or documentation for what to return in this case. What should I be returning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

keep your original code and try use ODataNullValueMessageHandler

```
        configuration.MapODataServiceRoute(
            "odata", 
            "odata", 
            GetEdmModel(configuration),
            defaultHandler: HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(innerHandler: new HttpControllerDispatcher(configuration), handlers: new[] { new ODataNullValueMessageHandler()}));
```

Comment: The issue is that it returns 'Sequence contains no elements' error.  I would rather return something akin to NotFound(). Although maybe that is the intended function of SingleResult?

Comment: I guess to clarify that comment, it returns an InvalidOperationException and a 500.  I would think it would be better to return something more useful with a 404. I just don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

As you have rightly identified, there are a number of potentially different responses that we may want to report back to the user, 200 and 404 are not enough.

We can add in handlers or filters to interpret exceptions and return more meaningful http response codes as explained in other answers, but that still doesn't help when you want to explicitly return a different HTTP response code such as 400-BadRequest or 404-NotFound.

> If you find yourself throwing arbitrary exceptions just so another process can interpret the message and reformat it into a usable response or something more meaningful, which is why we threw the exception in the first place, then you should evaluate whether an exception is the best mechanism to express the response in the first place.

We can be more expressive with exceptional code responses by changing the response type of your web method to `IHttpActionResult`. In most cases this change will be compatible with the rest of your Web API runtime.

Now from within your method we can easily express different common responses, if your controller class inherits from `ApiController` then the following example should work:

```
[EnableQuery]
public virtual IHttpActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    // HACK: Example of a specific case that we want to disallow
    if(key <= 0)
        return BadRequest("Keys must be positive values");

    using (var gateway = this.Gateway.GetChild())
    {
        var model = gateway.GetLoggerEntry(key);

        // Check for null and tell the client NotFound
        if(model == null)
            return NotFound();

        // NOTE: SingleResult does not implement IHttpActionResult and the ApiController 
        // does not provide a simple helper for SingleResult, so I've added one for you.
        return Single((new List<LoggerEntry>(){ model }).AsQueryable());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Helper to Create a SingleResult (200 OK) Response as IHttpActionResult
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of item in query.</typeparam>
/// <param name="itemQuery">The query to get the item.</param>
/// <returns>A System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult`1 with the specified values.</returns>
protected IHttpActionResult Single<T>(IQueryable<T> itemQuery)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, System.Web.Http.SingleResult.Create(itemQuery));
}
```

> NOTE: Many api developers who transition to using IHttpActionResult may choose to use the `protected internal virtual OkNegotiatedContentResult<T> Ok<T>(T content);` method to generate the IHttpActionResult response but this will always return an array even if your query results in a single row, that is why I have included the `Single` helper in my response.

In this case the `Single<T>` helper method demonstrates how you can easily customise the response handlers inside the controller class and give you back total control of the output, including how to specify different Status responses that might help make your code more expressive and readable to other team members.